# Difference of two positive semi-definite matrix still positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $X\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times p}$ is a real matrix with full column rank($n\geq p$), $B \in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive definite matrix, i.e all eigenvalue of matrix $B$ is positive, I want to show following matrix is still positive semi-definite.
$$B^{-1}-X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T $$
I attack this problem in two step.

First I assume $n=p$ which means that X is an invertible matrix, then $B^{-1}-X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T =B^{-1}-B^{-1}=\mathbf{0}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Second I want to show when $n>p$, I am not able to show this but I do some simulations. I just let $X_{ij}\sim N(0,1) $ randomly and let $B$ be any positive definite matrix, then I find all eigenvalue of $B^{-1}-X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T$ is greater or equal to zero, which implies positive-definiteness.

Can anybody give some hint on my second part, I'd like to get some theoretical proof. Really appreciated any suggestions and help!!

[new edited]
I realized I make a mistake in the statement of question, it should be $B^{-1}-X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T$ instead of $B-X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T$

Comment: Not valid, take $B$ diagonal or any positive definite matrix with eigenvalue equal to $\epsilon$ close to zero. Take $X$ the column matrix corresponding to the (unit) eigenvector of $\epsilon$, the entries of $X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T$ are not bounded so you conclude.

Comment: If $n=p$ and $X=I$ then $X(X^TBX)^{-1}X^T=B^{-1}.$ The matrix $B-B^{-1}$ is positive definite of all the eigenvalues of $B$ are greater than $1.$

Comment: Thanks for comments by Toni and Ryszard, I realized I make a mistake in the statement of question! now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since B is positive definite matrix, we know from matrix eigen-decomposition,
$$B=C^TC=C^2$$
where $C$ is "square root" of $B$, which is also  positive definite . To show $B^{-1}-X\left(X^T B X\right)^{-1} X^T$ is positive semi-definite, it suffices to show that $C[B^{-1}-X\left(X^T B X\right)^{-1} X^T]C^T$ is positive semi-definite. Define $Q=CX\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times p}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
C[B^{-1}-X\left(X^T B X\right)^{-1} X^T]C^T&=CB^{-1}C-CX(X^TC^TCX)^{-1}X^TC^T\\
&=I_n-Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T
\end{aligned}
$$
since rank of Q is $p\leq n$, $Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T$ has $n-p$ eigenvalue equal to $0$, other eigenvalue equal to 1. So $I_n-Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T$ is positive semi-definite.